# What class of near-earth asteroids would be most feasible for colonization?

Tags: colonization, asteroid

There are four types of near-earth asteroids:

- Apollo class asteroids, with orbits that intersect Earth and semi-major axes larger than Earth's
- Aten class asteroids, with orbits that intersect Earth and semi-major axes smaller than Earth's
- Amor class asteroids, with orbits that are completely between Earth and Mars
- Atira class asteroids, with orbits that are completely contained by Earth's.

My question is, what class of asteroids would be best for exploration? Habitiability comes first, and then cost.

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration! Your title question asks about colonization and then your body asks about exploration. They are different endeavors. Colonization is specifically about settling with inhabitants. Exploration is more general. In either case, "best" or "most feasible" are a little too broad and opinion-based to assess in a single question. Perhaps you could narrow your question to focus on a certain aspect, such as resources available to a colony.